# JavaScript prototype chain probable infinite cycle lookup

Tags: javascript, web, loops, proto

I have a query regarding JavaScript object prototype chains. Suppose I create an Object

```
var first =  { a: 1};
var second = Object.create(first);
```

Now I know that if I look up for the attribute `a` on the second object, due to the prototypal inheritance I would get the value `1`. But if suppose I assign `second` to the hidden `__ proto__` attribute of the first object, shouldn't the lookup get stuck in a look up cycle?

Here is what I mean:

```
first.__proto__ = second;
cosole.log(second.z); //Would it keep looking for both objects in a cycle?
```

Comment: Why do you think this would create an infinite lookup cycle?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: yeah I tried it in chrome console and the 4th statement is giving cyclic prototype error. How does chrome know its a cyclic prototype error?

Answer (score 1):

It does not enter into an infinite loop because **it doesn't HAVE to look into what the second object has in it**. Instead it shows that **there IS a second object** and then if you want to look further into it you can do so in separate steps.

Here is a quick example of what I mean in a pseudo code in order to make it more understandable:

```
OBJ 1 = {a:1}

OBJ 2 = Prototype of OBJ 1
Prototype of OBJ 1 = OBJ 2

print OBJ 2

Shows:
// Once again for clarity:
// The reason it is not entering into an infinite loop is because 
// it doesn't iterate through the prototype object and instead it SHOWS the prototype. 
// If you later want to see what's inside of it you can do so with an extra step. 
// But it gives you minimal available information and so you see this:

a: 1
proto: OBJ 1
```

Comment: When we check for an attribute on an object and if it is non existent then the prototype object of that object is checked and if it is not available on that object as well it climbs the prototype chain until it reaches the global Object prototype which is having null prototype. But since in our case the prototype of both objects are pointing to each other, I assume we will never reach the null prototype of Object. In chrome I ran the code it is giving the error "Cyclic `__ proto__` value". How does chrome JavaScript engine knows a cycle exists?

Comment: @ShowkatAli I assume it stores every `__proto__` that it is checked in some kind of array, and when it meets some `__ptoto__` that's already in the array, it stops. At least, this is implementation I used myself in a similar situation.